# What's the circuit for a PIR sensor?

Tags: sensor, motion

How does a motion detector work?

Comment: Insufficient preliminary research

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.logosfoundation.org/ii/infrared_sensing.html

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_infrared_sensor

Answer (score 2):

A PIR sensor usually contains two sensors (sometimes more), which look at different parts of the room through a multifaceted lens. The sensors readings are fed into a difference amplifier. If a person is stationary in the room each of the sensors will have a particular reading. If the person moves the lens will project the radiation differently onto the sensors, so that the difference amplifier's output will change. A differentiator will detect changes in the sensors' readings and switch the output.

In the past I've used Panasonic's [NaPiOn](http://www3.panasonic.biz/ac/e/control/sensor/human/napion/index.jsp) PIR sensor, which has a quad-type sensor, which, combined with the multifaceted lens divides the room in 64 detection zones.

[image]

Even small movements will cause a difference in the quad sensor, which will activate the output signal.